# jQuery datetimepicker does not update minDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am dealing with a previously written datetimepicker object.  It looks as follows:

```
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    monthNames: DATE_TIME_MONTHS_NAMES,
    monthNamesShort: DATE_TIME_MONTHS_NAMES_SHORT,
    dayNames: DATE_TIME_DAY_NAMES,
    dayNamesShort: DATE_TIME_DAY_NAMES_SHORT,
    dayNamesMin: DATE_TIME_DAY_NAMES_MIN,
    currentText: DATE_TIME_CURRENT,
    closeText: DATE_TIME_CLOSE,
    timeText: DATE_TIME_TIME,
    hourText: DATE_TIME_HOUR,
    minuteText: DATE_TIME_MINUTE,
    ampm: DATE_TIME_AMPM,
    dateFormat: DATE_TIME_FORMAT,
    timeFormat: 'h:mm tt',
    minDate: 0
});
```

I added

```
minDate: 0
```

so that it would only allow present or future date/times to be selected.  The datetimepicker works fine on the first click, as it shows the current date/time.  However, subsequent clicks still show the previous time and do not update to the current time.  Is there a way to reinitialize the datetimepicker on click so that it always grabs the current date/time?

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Best Regards,

-Dave F.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the property of existing object like this:

```
$('#startDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(YOUR_DATE_HERE));
```

Take a look here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option

Comment: I was able to determine a solution using the API that you provided me.  For some reason when I try the above method on click, it does not work.  I had to call the destroy method on click and then re-initialize the datetimepicker to get the time to update.  It still doesn't behave quite how I want it but it will work for now.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!!!